# import flask gives ImportError: No module named jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, importerror, python-2.6

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/pip2 install flask==0.12
Requirement already satisfied: flask==0.12 in /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: click>=2.0 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from flask==0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.6.egg (from flask==0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from flask==0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from flask==0.12)


$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 23 2015, 15:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import flask 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
ImportError: No module named jinja2
>>>
```

I get requirement already satisfied during install and then I get import error during import. Why is that ?

Comment: check to see if the directory is in your python path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't also have a `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jinja2`, it's possible that a prior install got interrupted. If that's the case, in your position I'd try removing `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Jinja2-2.6-py2.6.egg` and doing the install of flask==0.12 again.

There's a significantly newer version of Flask available (and Python, for that matter). I assume you have reasons for wanting something older.